# Error when uploading a video using instagram graph API

Tags: api, video, instagram-graph-api

I want to upload a video using the instagram graph api however the API asks for an **url** (and not a local path) for the video parameter. The video I want to upload is on my **desktop** (local) so I don't know how I can convert it so it works.

When I put a local path instead of the url I get the following message:
`

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 352,
        "error_subcode": 2207026,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Unsupported format",
        "error_user_msg": "The video format is not supported. Please check the specs for the supported streams format",
        "fbtrace_id": "AA3qcWZCmMsp0OfEE_m1cLJ"
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Try using something like ngrok.